# Applescript to find and move multiple files (but replacing some characters in the file name)

Tags: replace, find, applescript

A am a newcomer to applescript. 
I have a String with file names (without suffixes) separate by spaces, which I can copy.

I need to find and move multiple files from a single folder matching these file names.
I solved it with:
-pasting the String into a textEdit
-find and replace "Spaces with commas"
-run this code:

```
set fileContents to read (choose file with prompt "Choose a comma-delimited text file")
set theText to result
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set theTextItems to text items of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
theTextItems
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder") as string
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder")
repeat with theEPSName in theTextItems
    tell application "Finder"
        set theEPSFile to theSourceFolder & theEPSName
        move file theEPSFile to folder theDestination with replacing
    end tell
end repeat
```

I wanted to automate the whole process from copying the string of file names to the movement of files.

**Best solution:**
-script grabs the string from my clipboard (instead of "choose file with prompt")
-runs "find and replace" "spaces" by "commas"
-continues with find and move files

**Second best solution:**
-I save the file names into a textEdit
-"find and replace" "spaces" by "commas" is integrated into the applescript

Is there anyone with wizard knowledge to help me?
Would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

`(the clipboard as text)` will give you the clipboard contents as a string.

If whitespace is the original delimiter, you can just do `(words of (the clipboard as text))` and skip the steps with the commas and text item delimiters altogether.

`words of` doesn't care what kind of whitespace is between the 'words', or how many there are. It can be spaces, tabs, carriage returns, line feeds, and probably some other stuff, in whatever sequence, so you can format your input quite freely.

If you have one filename per line, you can use `paragraphs of` which may be safer, in case your filenames contain spaces.

Where's your text input coming from? You might be able to script that part too too. For example:

```
tell application "Finder" 
    set matches to (name of (files of window 1 whose name contains "foo"))
end tell
```

Clipboard contents seems like a dangerous thing to rely on, but ok.

Try something like this:

```
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose source folder") as string
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Choose destination folder")
repeat with theEPSName in (words of (the clipboard as text))
    tell application "Finder"
        set theEPSFile to theSourceFolder & theEPSName
        move file theEPSFile to folder theDestination with replacing
    end tell
end repeat
```

Comment: set fileContents to get the clipboard
set theText to result
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
set theTextItems to text items of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
theTextItems
set theSourceFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Source folder") as string
set theDestination to (choose folder with prompt "Target folder")
repeat with theEPSName in theTextItems
 tell application "Finder"
  set theEPSFile to theSourceFolder & theEPSName
  move file theEPSFile to folder theDestination with replacing
 end tell
end repeat

Comment: And this kind of works....!
BUT somehow I get an error:
-so if there is a file name in the text which has no file in the folder, the script stops.
Can I somehow solve this error interruption?
Behause it starts moving all files from the folder, until there is a file-name which doesn't exist.

Comment: Wrap the move in an if statement. Something like
`if file theEPSFile exists then move file theEPSFile end if`